# deny access to folders, but display content on the webpage

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block the video folder,so if someone would use the direct link of the video path in the DB, they would get the error.

But I want to display that video on my webpage.

So I denied the access of that folder in htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (^|/)videos(/|$) - [F]
```

But the videoplayer is just blank.(because of the 403 error)

Is this the right way? Can I allow my own page to access it? Or I should do it some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for displaying videos but lock it out from the public would be to use a CDN (Content Delivery Network) like Cloudflare to deliver and stream your videos and disallow the public to view all your videos in a folder.

Here is more information on Cloudflare's Video Hosting solution. 
https://www.cloudflare.com/products/cloudflare-stream/

I hope that helps answer your question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Found soulution, create new htaccess file and add it to your media folder. Allows access only from your site. Blocks direct request from elsewhere.

Put this into the file:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(mov|png|mp4)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://yoursite.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]